# ¿Cómo iterar y pasar al siguiente espacio de la misma linea?

Tags: python

Hola tengo el siguiente programa:

```
lista_elementos = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

    for i in lista_elementos:
        
        print('a')

        f = open('prueba.txt','a')
        f.write('a')
        f.close()
```

En el archivo txt todo me sale asi:

```
a
a
a
a
a
a
```

Deseo que me quede de la siguiente forma:

```
a  a  a  a  a  a
```

Comment: Tendrás que usar `.seek()` para moverte en el archivo y escribir desde el punto que quieras

Comment: Tal vez si añades los caracteres a un string en vez de hacer `write` y luego solo haces `write` del string te funcione. Cada vez que usas `write` se añade al final del archivo en una nueva línea. Saludos

Comment: No logro entender tu pregunta, el `write()` no agrega salto de línea al archivo, así que la salida no es como la muestras, si lo que quieres agregar un espacio, puedes hacer `f.write('a' + ' ')`